# Jupter Notebook 7 on MacBook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4, installed by Anaconda. When I open Anaconda, I can see that there is available Notebook 7 and I can read about migration plan on a https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html

> They said that I should run pip install notebook, but this doesn't change anything and I still have the same version of Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate_to_notebook7.html) carefully:

> For users who don’t use extensions or other customizations, you will seamlessly receive the new Notebook 7 when you pip install notebook **once version 7 is released out**

It is not released yet.

You can do

`pip install --pre notebook` to install a pre-release version

Do **not** do this though to overwrite a notebook version that was installed with `anaconda`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was just confused because they everywhere tell me about this update. So I will wait, thank you :)